# Is this use of concession correct?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tientsin_incident I read *An additional problem for the British was normally the **concession** police handed over Chinese suspects to the Tientsin police to be tried by Chinese courts*

Can *concession* really be used like that? What does the sentence mean?

Comment: I suspect there are major problems with the sentence. I'm guessing it should read: << An additional problem for the British was this: the concession included a stipulation that police should hand over Chinese suspects to the Tientsin police to be tried by Chinese courts. This was the normal practice. But .... >>

Comment: A concession is a compromise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I felt that too, that several words are missing or something like that.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Is it? I thought it more meant something like admission or accommodation.

Comment: Yes, a concession is an accommodation. That's how you compromise, a little give, a little get.

Comment: If you read the article, "concession" is being used to mean an area of the country that is placed under the authority of a foreign government.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overlook one meaning of **concession** given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/concession) as:

> The right to use land or other property for a specified purpose, granted by a government, company, or other controlling body.

Various foreign countries had concessions in China, usally for trading purposes, similar to a commercial concession in a airport. Reading the Wikipedia article it is clear this is the meaning of the word. So in your sentence there is a *noun adjunct* phrase

> concession police

In other words, the police acting within the concession area, on behalf of the British administration, who would only deal with the British residents themselves. But before then, they had dealt with all trouble makers as shown by this extract:

> the worse thing that would happen to them if captured by the **concession police** was to be held in the local jail, which was considered vastly preferable to being tortured and executed by the Japanese

Comment: A well placed dash would have made thing much easier...